# PHP/SQL messages algorithm

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, session

Hi I am a sixth form computing student making a website for coursework. It involves a basic messaging system that retrieves all messages from a database that is sent to the users id. I have made an algorithm that creates a table to display all the results however there is one flaw that I cannot solve. Along with the senders name, there is a hyperlink that goes to person.php - a page that displays other users profiles. It works like a template which is filled by the users information on the database. To get the other users information I am using sessions. $_SESSION['userid2'] is what holds the userid of the latest viewed person. However when the while statement loops again, userid2 is rewritten to the id of the person who sent the latest message. This means when you click on any name it sends you to person.php, but it will load the profile of the last person to send a message. To get around this I have tried making different variable names for each message but the problem with this is retreiving the name of the variable when clicked. I have also tried using functions and onClick() but all is to no prevail. Could an array work? Or any other php functions? 
Please feel free to ask any questions and any help is greatly appreciated. The loop is written bellow.

```
<?php
$n=0;
echo "<table width='1350' border='0' align='center'><br>";
echo "<tbody><br>";
echo "<tr><br>";
echo "<td width='200' bgcolor='#35312f' align='center' valign='middle'>Date</td><br>";
echo "<td width='200' bgcolor='#35312f' align='center' valign='middle'>Name</td><br>";
echo "<td width='950' bgcolor='#35312f' align='center' valign='middle'>Contents</td><br>";
echo "<tr>";
while ($n < $num_rows) {
    mysqli_data_seek($result, $n);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo "<tr><br>";
    echo "<td bgcolor='#35312f'>".$data['date']."</td><br>";
    echo "<td bgcolor='#35312f'><a href='person.php'>".$data['firstname']." ".$data['secondname']."</a></td><br>";
    echo "<td bgcolor='#35312f'>".$data['contents']."</td><br>";
    echo "</tr><br>";

    $n = ($n + 1);
}
echo "</tbody><br>";
echo "</table><br>";
?>
```

Comment: So basically you are trying to get the profile of the user whose name is clicked on, correct?

Comment: You could use a url param, i.e. `person.php?id=$data['userid2']`. And then instead of `$_SESSION['userid2']` you would use `$_GET['id']`

Comment: @Imperialized yes that's correct and it needs their id to get their profile information.

Comment: Yeah, Sean is correct if that is what you are trying to achieve. Make sure to sanitize your variables or use a prepared statement.

Comment: @Sean will that not overwrite when the loop cycles?

Comment: No. If you do that in the loop, it will create a unique url per user, just like the `$data['firstname']`/etc. So it would look something like `<a href='person.php?id=".$data['userid2']."'>` (although the `id=` could be `userid=` or any other key name.

Comment: Success! Thank you both for the help much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome (and encouraged) to write up an answer to your own question, and mark it as accepted, so this question no longer shows as unanswered. Alternatively you can delete the question if you don't feel it and the resulting answer will provide any help to future visitors.